# PHP Mailer muy lento al enviar un email

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

estoy teniendo problemas con la libreria de phpmailer. Llevo 5 meses trabajando con ella y enviando email, mediante un formulario, funcionaba muy rapido, el proceso tardaba medio segundo, pero a patir de antes de ayer empezo a tardar mas de 5 segundos al enviar un mensaje, tiempo el cual es muy prologando.

Quisiera saber por donde podria venir el error, o a que se debe esa lentitud, sabiendo que el script, el código no ha sido modificado. El proyecto está en produccion alojado en un hosting que se ha portado bien hasta ahora sin problemas de conexion.

- El primer problema que me me dio, fue que no enviaba el email y me salia error de conexion con el host.
- Luego investigue y pasandole la configuracion de mail SMTPOptions en un array se solucionaba, lo hice y funciono, pero tardaba demasiado en enviar email.
- Le cambie el email para ver si era el que estaba provocando problemas, y siguio tardando de la misma manera

Este es mi código:

```
        use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
         use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

          require '../phpmailer/PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
          require '../phpmailer/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
         require '../phpmailer/PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';

           enviarEmail();

           function enviarEmail(){
         if(isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['asunto']) && isset($_POST['cod_orden'])){
 //mandar correo
 $id_orden=$_POST['id_orden'];
 $identificacion_cliente=$_POST['identificacion_cliente'];
 $cod_orden=$_POST['cod_orden'];

 $email=$_POST['email'];
 $asunto=$_POST['asunto'];

 $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

 try {
     //Server settings

     $mail->SMTPDebug = false; 
     $mail->do_debug = 0; 
                           // Enable verbose debug output
     $mail->isSMTP();                                            // Send using SMTP
     $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';                    // Set the SMTP server to send through
     $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
     $mail->Username   = '----';                     // SMTP username
     $mail->Password   = '----';                               // SMTP password
     $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';         // Enable TLS encryption; `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` encouraged
     $mail->Port       = 587;           
     $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
);                         // TCP port to connect to, use 465 for `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` above
 
     //Recipients
     $mail->setFrom('----', 'Informes-Express');
     $mail->addAddress($_POST['email']);     // Add a recipient
    
 
 
     // Content
     $mail->isHTML(true); 
     $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';                                 // Set email format to HTML
     $mail->Subject = ($_POST['asunto']);
     $mail->Body ='<!DOCTYPE html>

     //ACA VA EL CUERPO DEL MENSAJE

       $mail->send();
        header('location:../vistas/mensajes/respuestas/enviado.php');
    } catch (Exception $e) {
       echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
      }

    }else{
    return;

   }
 }
```

Si alguien le ha ocurrido lo mismo le agradeceria un comentario.

le quite el

```
        $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
            'ssl' => array(
             'verify_peer' => false,
             'verify_peer_name' => false,
             'allow_self_signed' => true
           )
      );
```

y activé el debug. Me dio este error:

```
2020-08-11 13:31:29 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP x57sm19329801qtc.61 - gsmtp
2020-08-11 13:31:29 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO ############
2020-08-11 13:31:29 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [192.99.46.110]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-STARTTLS250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
2020-08-11 13:31:29 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2020-08-11 13:31:29 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
2020-08-11 13:31:44 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2020-08-11 13:31:44
2020-08-11 13:31:44
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
```

Comment: Evita las mayúsculas sostenidas, por favor. Se entiende como que estás gritando (y veo que no es la idea)

Comment: Sobre tu problema, ¿está claro que el servicio SMTP es esencialmente una cola de mensajería que va despachando los mensajes pero que no es un servicio síncrono? Que tu script PHP se termine de ejecutar sólo llega a dejarle un nuevo elemento a la cola del servicio SMTP, pero los tiempos de envío de ese servicio son independientes.

Comment: De eso me estoy dando cuenta ahora. Lo que me parece raro es la velocidad con la que antes lo enviaba.

Comment: Bueno, tiene sentido lo que dices y es asi. Lo que quiero saber es porque antes el envio era mas rapido. Si bien al final del script tengo un redireccionamiento a un link  cuando el mensaje fue enviado.  $mail->send();
         header('location:../vistas/mensajes/respuestas/enviado.php');
     } catch (Exception $e) {
         echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
     }

  }else{
    return;

  }
}

Comment: Yo haría dos revisiones: 1) habilitar las opciones de debug para ver qué sale en logs de apache/php; 2) como estás en un hosting, buscaría la forma de revisar que no estén usando el servicio para enviar spam. Ver que no haya cuentas default, envío anónimo, etc. Lo que hagas después del `send()` no influye en lo que pase con el envío. Pues, a menos que hagas unos cálculos matemáticos muy intensos, no vas a demorar la cola que se conecta al servicio SMTP.

Comment: Edite la pregunta, te invito a leerla nuevamente.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111672/discussion-between-alfabravo-and-alvaro-aliaga).

Comment: Le quite la smtpOption array() y deja d enviar el mensaje, Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. Y siempre sirvio. Puede ser que gmail haya detectado al hosting o la url como spam?

Comment: Revisa el chat, por favor. La idea es no tener discusiones largas en los comentarios. Allá te dejé mi impresión de lo que pasa. Lleva tus comentarios adicionales al chat que te sugiero

Comment: Resuelto por Alfabravo